# @Autowired UserRepository null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, repository

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? При попытке обратиться к методу сервиса, появляется исключение NPE т.к. userService null

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.dtbots.demo.repositories")
public class BotsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BotsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@Component
public class TelegramMain implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new TelegramMessageInviter());
        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        main(args);
    }
}
```

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService; //null

if (!userService.getUserBySystemId((long) update.getMessage().getFrom().getId()).isPresent()) {
                    User user = User.builder()
                            .systemId((long) update.getMessage().getFrom().getId())
                            .from(TypeFrom.TELEGRAM)
                            .build();
                    userService.addUser(user);
}
```

```
@Component
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> getUserBySystemId(Long systemId) {
        return userRepository.findUserBySystemId(systemId);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> getUserById(Long id) {
        return userRepository.findUserById(id);
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
    Optional<User> findUserBySystemId(Long systemId);
    Optional<User> findUserById(Long userId);
}
```

Comment: у вас спринг бут? для начала аннотацию @SpringBootApplication добавьте над классом BotsApplication

Comment: Да, бут. Прошу прощения, забыл скопировать эту аннотацию

Comment: а что это за кусок кода, в котором у вас инжектится userService? он в каком классе?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/eXm04PQInluWjw

Comment: здесь вопросы можно редактировать, если что-то нужно добавить. над классом, который на скриншоте, есть аннотация , делающая его бином? если да, то это здорово, но я вижу, как вы создаете экземпляр этого класса  в классе TelegramMain через new, а значит выходите за предел контекста спринга.

Comment: Вроде решил вопрос. Спасибо!

Comment: да не за что. был бы весь исходный код, можно было сказать за пару минут, но поскольку видно не все, то приходится угадывать и задавать вопросы. но такая проблема в целом возникает по 2 причинам: вышли за пределы контекста (создали через new и потом в нем инжектим), либо пакет, в котором находится класс, не был просканирован спрингом, как следствие, бин не найден и не создан.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь выше, вроде нашел решение.
Добавил эту зависимость

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
     <artifactId>telegrambots-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
     <version>4.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Далее в **BotsApplication** переместил строчку: 
`ApiContextInitializer.init();`
Убрал класс **TelegramMain** и пометил класс **TelegramMessageInviter** аннотацией `@Component`